# Postgres SQL (Amazon Redshift) - How to calculate distance between two latitude and longitudes?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In Netezza I am used to using the INZA package and ST_Distance function. Does anybody know of a similar way in Redshift? I use this for a lot of calculations and joins.

Answer (score 8):

check this out!!

```
------- DISTANCE FUNCTION ---------
CREATE FUNCTION DISTANCE (orig_lat float, orig_long float, dest_lat float, dest_long float)
  RETURNS float
STABLE  
AS $$
  import math
  r = 3963.1676          
  phi_orig = math.radians(orig_lat)
  phi_dest = math.radians(dest_lat)
  delta_lat = math.radians(dest_lat - orig_lat)
  delta_long = math.radians(dest_long - orig_long)
  a = math.sin(delta_lat/2) * math.sin(delta_lat/2) + math.cos(phi_orig) \
      * math.cos(phi_dest) * math.sin(delta_long/2) * math.sin(delta_long/2)
  c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
  d = r * c
  return d
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu
;
```

Answer (score 3):

while there's nothing wrong with the python udf approach, we've found that python udf's take way longer and consume way more resources than native sql udf's (and we run this over billions of records).  This is what we use, and it's certainly not perfect (i.e. we are averaging the radius of the earth to 3961 miles, but we didn't need to be exact for our use).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_haversine (
  float, -- $1: latitude_1
  float, -- $2: longitude_1
  float, -- $3: latitude_2
  float  -- $4: longitude_2
)  
  RETURNS FLOAT
  IMMUTABLE
AS $$
  SELECT 2 * 3961 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER((SIN(RADIANS(($3 - $1) / 2))) , 2) + COS(RADIANS($1)) * COS(RADIANS($3)) * POWER((SIN(RADIANS(($4 - $2) / 2))) , 2) ))
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

This is just a manual calculation of the haversine distance using built-in sql math functions.  This will return the distance in miles, if you want to return it in another unit of measure, you can replace the `3961` with the average radius of the earth in what ever unit you want (i.e. `6371` for kilometers, or `6371000` for meters, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The postgres_fdw module that alexanderlz suggested won't work with Redshift since the minimum requirement is Postgres 8.1 (for read-only). Redshift currently uses Postgres 8.0.2. You could use [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/dblink.html) instead to get similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to calculate it **outside** redshift,

you can try the following:

- GeoDis (redis based) https://github.com/doat/geodis
- PostGis (postgres) http://postgis.net/

Since redshift implements postgres interface, you can take advantage of postgres [FDW](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) abilities, and unite them to a single postgres datasource, where you can do your joins in a single query.

i.e. : instance of postgres (call it "master"), with postgis installed, which connects to redshift through **fdw**. this way you can use geolocation queries on your redshift data.

Comment: Not (no longer?) correct. Redshift implements enough math functions to calculate this using Haversine Formula or similar.